# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

This is the code within my SAVE button in the form. I'm using VB6.0 and MSSQL Server 2005.

CommonDialog1 & 2 holds the filename of the image inserted in the picture box.

```vb
Set rs = con.Execute("insert into table1   
values('" & txtbox1.Text & "' , "_  
& " '" & txtbox2.Text & "' , "_     
& " '" & CommonDialog1.FileName & "' , "_    
& " '" & CommonDialog2.FileName & "' , "_  
& " '" & txtbox3.Text & "' )")
```

The **"Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."** - error pops up during run-time.

Comment: Hellloooo SQL Injection. Even with classic VB and ADO, you can still use a [Command object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502(v=vs.85).aspx) that allows you to use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Since "INSERT" function of SQL does not accept subquery, I tried converting the filename of the CommonDialog1 & 2 using **CAST** and it was a success.

Set rs = con.Execute("insert into table1
values('" & txtbox1.Text & "' , "_
& " '" & txtbox2.Text & "' , "_
**& " cast('" & CommonDialog1.FileName & "' as varbinary(max)) , "_

& " cast('" & CommonDialog2.FileName & "' as varbinary(max)), "_**
& " '" & txtbox3.Text & "' )")

Comment: Congratulations. You've stored the *file name* in a `varbinary(max)` column. But given the column definition, I'd have expected that it was created to store the actual contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever but is there other way on how to store the actual contents of the file? e.g. store the image directly into the database . I'm using this code to get the filename of the image: 'CommonDialog1.showopen'  picturebox1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create yourself a stored procedure (can be done without, but I prefer this method) with the parameters listed below (I suggest renaming them)
2. Replace the line mCmd.CommandText with your stored procedure name
3. Replace the connection string
4. If any of the text sizes are wrong, correct the parameter size

> ```
> Dim mConn As New ADODB.Connection
> Dim mCmd As New ADODB.Command
> Dim mStreamCD1 As New ADODB.Stream
> Dim mStreamCD2 As New ADODB.Stream
>
> mStreamCD1.Type = adTypeBinary
> mStreamCD1.Open
> mStreamCD1.LoadFromFile (CommonDialog1.FileName)
>
> mStreamCD2.Type = adTypeBinary
> mStreamCD2.Open
> mStreamCD2.LoadFromFile (CommonDialog2.FileName)
>
> mConn.Open "Insert your Connection String"
> Set mCmd.ActiveConnection = mConn
> mCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
>
> mCmd.CommandText = "InsertIntoTable1"
> mCmd.Parameters.Append mCmd.CreateParameter("@txtbox1Text", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250, txtbox1.Text)
> mCmd.Parameters.Append mCmd.CreateParameter("@txtbox2Text", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250, txtbox2.Text)
> mCmd.Parameters.Append mCmd.CreateParameter("@CD1", adVarBinary, adParamInput, mStreamCD1.Size, mStreamCD1.Read)
> mCmd.Parameters.Append mCmd.CreateParameter("@CD2", adVarBinary, adParamInput, mStreamCD2.Size, mStreamCD2.Read)
> mCmd.Parameters.Append mCmd.CreateParameter("@txtbox3Text", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250, txtbox3.Text)
>
> mCmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
> ```